# How to recieve data on serial port synchronously?

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I have the following set up: a computer that runs Linux (TCL) and device that sends packets of fixed length (10 bytes) with fixed frequency (100 Hz).

On computer, i have that serial port open, and i am trying to read incoming data. However, instead of recieving it in 10-byte chunks all the time, lesser amounts of data are being read, and i am forced to reassemble them back.

My goal is to send a responce for each packet once it arrives, preserving intervals between packets as much as possible.

This is how i open the serial port:

```
int fd = open(device_name, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
if(fd == -1)
{
    LOGPRINT("Failed to open terminal file.\nError #%d (%s)\n",
           errno, strerror(errno));
        return fd;
}

LOGPRINT("Setting terminal attributes\n");
struct termios config;
struct termios *pterm = &config;
// set baud rate

LOGPRINT("Setting baud rate to %d.\n", baud_rates[baud_rate_index]);
// change to raw mode
LOGPRINT("Setting terminal to raw mode\n");
pterm->c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR
                    | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
pterm->c_oflag &= OPOST;
pterm->c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
cfsetispeed(pterm, baud_bits[pconfig->baud_rate_index]);
cfsetospeed(pterm, baud_bits[pconfig->baud_rate_index]);
LOGPRINT("Set character size, parity and stop bit flags.\n");
// set character size
pterm->c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
pterm->c_cflag |= csize_flag;
// set parity
pterm->c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);
pterm->c_cflag |= parity_flag;
// set stopbits
pterm->c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
pterm->c_cflag |= stopbits_flag;

// enable reading; ignore control lines
pterm->c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;
// disable flow control

pterm->c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
pterm->c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
LOGPRINT("Flush terminal.\n");
// flush terminal
tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);
LOGPRINT("Apply parameters.\n");
return WRAPSYSCALL(tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, pterm));
```

Additionally i set the following on file descriptor with fnctl:

```
int flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | FASYNC | O_DIRECT);
```

I am reading from file descriptor in a cycle with `select()` call on file descriptor set containing `fd`, then reading all bytes avaiable (requesting number of bytes much bigger then 10).

What should i change to ensure incoming data are processed as they come properly, in timely manner?

Comment: 'lesser amounts of data are being read, and i am forced to reassemble them back' - yes, this is normal with serial byte streams, as is the use of an apropriate protocol to establish message boundaries.

Comment: I am worried about the reason. If that happens because not all data of recieved packet make it to the file buffer at once, that means i read the rest of packet only when next on earrives, which defeats the purpose of answering packets as they arrive

Comment: Most drivers will post off any remaining buffered data if no more arrives within some timeout, typically 3-5 character intervals.

Comment: Your program needs to initialize the termios structure (before it starts to modify its contents) by calling **tcgetattr()**.  If this is a C program for Linux, what is the purpose of WRAPSYSCALL()?  If you're encountering receive issues, then you should show all your code, including the writes as well as the reads.  It's impossible to analyze/debug a program with snippets of code and vague descriptions of the other pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your program does nothing else than waiting for bytes and answering, then you can try using blocking file operations. Remove `O_NONBLOCK` flag from your `open` function call, and after setting the port just do a `read(fd, buffer, 10)`. The function will return after it reads exactly 10 bytes (or an error happens or signal arrives).

However, bear in mind that you read operation can start in the middle of packet transmission, so for example you can get last x bytes of n-th packet and first 10-x of packet n+1.

Comment: The OP should use blocking mode, since the code specifies raw (non-canonical) mode.  The VMIN and VTIME specifications are ignored when the port is configured in nonblocking mode.  BTW the length argument in **read()** specifies a maximum length, and may not return *exactly* the length as you wrote.

Comment: well, yes, if i specify ten, as far as i know, there is nothing prevening read() returning with 2 or 6 bytes.

Comment: @Srv19: If you use blocking read only a signal/error could terminate system call. In other circumstances it should return 10.